# Ignore warnings for the file placed in .eslintignore

Tags: eslint

I have placed certain files in `.eslintignore` in my project directory. Though the errors which I was getting earlier have been gone, I still keep getting a warning message for those files.

> 0:0  warning  File ignored because of a matching ignore pattern. Use
>   "--no-ignore" to override

eg. of the files ignored are,

```
src/**/*.scss
src/**/*.svg
```

using this command to run eslint, `eslint src/*`

How do I remove these warnings?

Comment: `eslint src`? By including `*` your shell is expanding all of the files, including non-JS, and explicitly passing them to ESLint.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I tried that, but I am getting No files matching the pattern "src" were found.

Comment: Maybe `src/.`; I usually just use `eslint .` then exclude e.g. `dist/` in the `.eslintignore`.

Comment: `src/.` `./src/.`  not working either, giving the same error, not sure why?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me,

```
eslint "src/**"
```

when passing the parameter in double-quotes, it uses node glob syntax to expand.

ref: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface

Comment: To expand on that: when you pass `eslint src/**`, the glob gets expanded into all matching files ***and passed to eslint as a huge command line arguments list***, so eslint is being passed "src/foo/bar.scss" as command line argument, then told to ignore it by the eslintignore file. But when you pass the glob in quotes, as this answer shows, eslint is the one responsible for figuring out which files to check.